# Python code is displayed on screen when `Ctrl + C` button hit on Windows 10. How to hide this?

Tags: python

This is simple Python code on Windows. The problem is when I hit Ctrl + C, some of the code will be displayed on the screen even though I have already converted .py to .exe using pyinstaller

**Code**

```
C:\code>more test.py
#!/usr/bin/python

print("\n Hello")
input(" Pause ... ")

C:\code>
```

**Normal execution**

```
C:\code>python test.py

 Hello
 Pause ...

C:\code>
```

**Ctrl + C during execution ... before code paused**

```
C:\code>python test.py

 Hello
 Pause ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    input(" Pause ... ")
KeyboardInterrupt

C:\code>
```

Would it be possible to hide this code even someone hit Ctrl + C during code execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap the code in a try-except statement

```
try:
    print("\n Hello")
    input(" Pause ... ")
except KeyboardInterrupt as ki:
    pass
```

Comment: @wim this question is nearly 5 years old, and the user accepted it. your comment is not relevant

Comment: The age of the question and whether or not the user accepted is irrelevant to its correctness. Only the content of the answer matters, and this answer remains incorrect.

Comment: @wim the answer is correct as marked by the OP. You have no idea what they wanted.

Comment: OPs select incorrect answers very often; an answer being _accepted_ is not proof of its _correctness_. Please have a read of [_Proper handling of SIGINT/SIGQUIT_](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html) to understand why this answer is deficient.